# how to apply the multi regression on categorical data in python

Tags: python-3.x

i have a data set of restaurant and i want to forecast that which item would sale more in future on the base of sale and date here is a Screen shot of my data set.[it is a code i am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ued5E.png)

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Restaurant = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Muhammad Akmal/Desktop/CSV dataset/dataset.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(Restaurant,columns=['Item','Date','Quantity','Unit_Cost','Basic_Cost ','Delivery_Charges','Service_Charges','Net_Cost','Basic_Selling_Price','Discount','Selling_Price','Tax','Cash _Received','Profit'])
print (df)

dum=pd.get_dummies(Restaurant['Item'])
print(dum)

plt.scatter(df['Date'], df['dum'], color='red')
plt.title('Stock Index Price Vs Interest Rate', fontsize=14)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Item', fontsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[but it is giving me the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRqEW.png)
how can i plot the items with date and quantity. please help me out [it is a screen shoot of my data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URcCF.png)

Comment: Hi, WC to SO. Here as a community we support the code i.e efforts first. Can you please share what have you tried first ?

Comment: dum=pd.get_dummies(Restaurant['Item'])
print(dum)

Comment: when i am ploting the data dum with date it is giving error

Comment: @Memom can you update the question with proper code formatting and the error ?

Comment: check it now @yash

Comment: @Memom update the code in the question for better visibility and editing

Comment: i have done now

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand "dum" is a different dataframe and its not a column in df, This error just means that the key you are looking for is not in df (Data frame).

-Harsha

Comment: how can i plot the items as item are a categorical data can you plzz help me out

Comment: I didnt understand your requirement completely but please checkout this link for some plotting ideas https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html